# Width of all contained elements + width of last element

Tags: jquery, width

I need a container div to be the combined width of all its images, plus the width of the last image. Ive got the width of the combined images with this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.pressimage').each(function() {
        var totalImageWidth = 0;

        $("img", this).each(function () {
            totalImageWidth += $(this).width();
        });

        $(this).width(totalImageWidth);
    });
});
```

So how can I now add the width of the last image? Ive tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $('.pressimage').each(function() {
        var totalImageWidth = 0;

        $("img", this).each(function () {
            totalImageWidth += $(this).width();
        });


        $("img", this).last(function () {
            lastImageWidth = $(this).width();
        });

        $(this).width(totalImageWidth + lastImageWidth);
    });
});
```

Thanks

UPDATE. 
Sorry, I was working on the wrong code. Here's what I have which makes the div the width of all its images:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    var pub_accum_width = 0;

    $('.view-public-collection .pubimagecolor').find('img').each(function() {
        pub_accum_width += $(this).width();
    });
    //alert(pub_accum_width);

        $('.view-public-collection .view-content').width(pub_accum_width);

});
```

And here is my modified code, but it hasn't made the div any wider:

```
$(window).load(function() {


    var pub_accum_width = 0;
    var pub_accum_last = 0;

    $('.view-public-collection .pubimagecolor').find('img').each(function() {
            pub_accum_width += $(this).width();
    });


    $('.view-public-collection .pubimagecolor').find('img').last(function() {
        pub_last_width += $(this).width();
    });


    $('.view-public-collection .view-content').width(pub_accum_width + pub_last_width);


});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ANSWER FOR UPDATED QUESTION:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var pub_accum_width = 0;
    var pub_last_width = 0; // not pub_accum_last

    $('.view-public-collection .pubimagecolor').find('img').each(function() {
        pub_accum_width += $(this).width();
    });

    //                                                   ...last(function(...
    $('.view-public-collection .pubimagecolor').find('img').last().each(function() {
        pub_last_width += $(this).width();
    });

    $('.view-public-collection .view-content').width(pub_accum_width + pub_last_width);
});
```

`last()` is a separate traversing function, you can not add a callback parameter to it. Select the last element with it, then use `each()`. Also you use different variable names.

---

You have to define the `lastImageWidth` variable outside of the <strike>`last()` callback</strike> `each()` callback after `last()`, to be able to use it outside again.

```
// ...
var totalImageWidth = 0;
var lastImageWidth = 0;
// ...
```

Comment: Sorry, i posted the wrong code. Ive updated my main post as you cant really post code in these comments. Thanks

Comment: My first section of code also needs last() be used in the same way.

Comment: You mean the part be fore you updated the question? Yea, right, I did not notice that earlier, just in the updated code.

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. I just thought id mention it incase it helps anyone else who comes across this post. Thanks again.